# no *the* in "from beginning to end"

Tags: idioms, zero-article

> We listened to the old man tell his story *from beginning to end*.

How come that it is not *from **the** beginning to **the** end*? It is the beginning and the end of the particular story. The only explanation I can think of is that *from beginning to end* is kind of an idiomatic adverb meaning *completely*, and you cannot alter this adverb.

Comment: **tell his story...?*

Comment: @MaulikV: Yes, it is from the Murphy's grammar, if trust this book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your explanation is right. It's an idiomatic phrase. I don't think "from the beginning to the end" sounds bad, if you want to say that.

In general this idiom is "productive," i.e. you can do the same construction whenever you mean the whole scope of something. So, "I scanned the wall from top to bottom," "I ran the race from start to finish," etc. And in all of these examples it's fine to put "the" in front of both nouns or neither. (Don't put "the" in front of one noun, since you can't mix the idiomatic phrase with normal speech.) "From A to Z" is another common one.

Comment: also: from front to back, from left to right, from soup to nuts, from head to toe, from dawn to dusk, not to mention all the "from X to X" idioms: from time to time, from side to side, from coast to coast, from ear to ear, from door to door, from point to point