What is the difference between "this is a beginning" and "this is beginning"?
This context comes from the movie "Se7en" by David Fincher.
In this movie, there is a scene in which Detective Somerset is explaining to his boss that the murder case they are investigating is the work of a serial killer. He provides some evidence to support that claim and then concludes:
"It means that this is beginning."
[He means that this is the beginning of a series of murders that will happen in the future following a certain pattern that he believes the murderer will follow.]
I don't understand why there isn't either a definite or indefinite article before the word "beginning". I know that it can function as both countable/uncountable noun but I don't know why. In fact, the part of the sample sentence "from beginning to end" also seems to be missing the article.
Is this because "beginning" in both of these sentences refers to the general idea of a beginning? I.E. they don't refer to the concrete beginning of the book or series of murders but the beginning as a general idea of a certain time period that could be applied to anything (or not necessarily applied but just exists as a concept understandable to human mind?)
Courtesy of Cambridge Dictionary

A2 [C usually singular, U]
the first part of something or the start of something:
Notes on how to use this dictionary can be found at the beginning of the book.
She sat down and read the book straight through from beginning to end.
I enjoyed my job at/in the beginning (= when I started it), but I'm bored with it now.


In 'this is a beginning', beginning is a noun; in 'this is beginning', the same word is a verb. The meanings are different and can be checked from a good dictionary.

The pattern "from X to Y" is normally without articles, e.g. "from head to toe," "from A to Z," "from soup to nuts." This is most true when this is being used idiomatically and figuratively, but might not be when literal: "I ran from the Eiffel Tower to a nearby cafe."


It means that this is beginning

It means that the series of murders is [just] beginning
This is an example of the Present Continuous form, we don't normally use articles before verbs, the verb begin can be replaced with start
    (a) I am beginning/starting to dislike my coworker.
PAST I was beginning/starting to dislike…
    (b) He’ll begin/start his new job on Monday.
PAST He began/started his new job…
    (c) We should begin/start today.
PAST We should have begun/started yesterday.
In the beginning…
In this instance beginning is a noun, the phrase is used in The Book of Genesis:

In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
King James Version (1611)

The noun phrase is a fixed expression and is not replaceable with at the start
from beginning to end
This structure without articles can be found in idioms and phrases such as:

from time to time
from top to bottom
from A to Z
from cover to cover
from 9 (am) to 5 (pm)
from London to New York
from 1939 to 1945


Hi. I upvoted your good answer.You edited the question very nice. Thank you very much for your help. You helped me to answer correctly the question about the subject of generalising. I answered it correctly but they downvoted it.

Instead of going in length and create confusions I shall make it simple by just addressing your two queries:
I. Why no definite article in Detective Somerset's dialogue?

I don't understand why there isn't either a definite or indefinite article before the word "beginning".

Your enquiry is about this sentence:

"It means that this is beginning."

This sentence can be rewritten as :
It means that the series of murders (this) is beginning..
Here beginning is a verb so no article is used. (Series is collective noun, so singular verb "is")
II. Why no definite article in sample sentence?.

I don't know why. In fact, the part of the sample sentence "from beginning to end" also seems to be missing the article.

She sat down and read the book straight through from beginning to end.
Notes on how to use this dictionary can be found at the beginning of the book.
I enjoyed my job at/in the beginning  .


Sentence 1: Article "the" is not used because "beginning to end" is an idiom. It is explained in the ELL link.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/no-the-in-from-beginning-to-end#:~:text=The%20only%20explanation%20I%20can,you%20cannot%20alter%20this%20adverb.
In sentence 2: "the" is used because it is a specific beginning of the book.
Sentence 3: Specific beginning of "my job" justifies using "the"

@Mari-LouA Thank you for pointing that out.

The differences in meaning are extremely subtle, and answering your question at all, requires native competency.
"A beginning," in English, refers to a specific event, defining a beginning, emphasizing a beginning.  A related expression is "A new beginning."  Usually, the beginning referred to in English, is a positive event.
"The silver lining still remains, the sights I've left to see [...] So trust that, with this end, a new beginning's waiting patiently."
"Beginning", in English, emphasizes a continuity of events, of which this is one.  Also, this particular beginning has no inflection of positivity or negativity associated with it, except from the context.
"Primrose season is beginning in east Texas."
Other native authors may reasonably disagree.

I'm not sure it "requires native competency" or offers room for disagreement to tell a noun from a verb based on the rest of the sentence; that's the main difference with your primroses and the source of the OP's misunderstanding.

@Michael Harvey So beginning is not an uncount noun in the English language? I.e. "beginning" in "This is beginning" can never function as a noun? Cambridge Dictionary lists this noun as both count and uncount. Can you give me some examples of this word as a non-count noun?

@AndyBonner Can you elaborate on what is the "patter from X to Y" and why you included as an example of it "from A to Z"? I understand when someone says "from A to B" (A & B being anything really).

@StaticBounce I suspect the only "uncount noun" sense is in that "from __ to __" usage. The movie quote here is just a verb. And yes, I was just using X and Y as you just used A and B, or as I just used dashes, variables to represent "anything really."
